# Why is io request sent that many times?

Tags: javascript, web-services, yui

I'm new to **Yui** but still plan on understanding it. Therefore, I need you ! I'm have a bit of a problem and haven't found any solution yet. Here is the plan  :

I have a button and when I click on it, that button will send Json to a webservice. If it was sent successfully, I get a 'success' alert and 'failure' otherwise.

Here is the problem :

- I **click on the button** once, I get **1 success alert** (ok)
- I **click one more time**, I get **2 success alerts** (why two ??)
- I **click a third time** and get **3 more success alerts**...
- I refresh the page, click the button and get 1 success alert

So why is that ? Why would it display twice the alert the second time ?
Here is the Yui code I am using :

```
    YUI().use('io-base', 'json', 'event', 'querystring-stringify-simple', function (Y) {
    Y.one('#connectBut').on('tap', function (e){

        var jsonCreateUser = {
                "login": "01234",
                "password": "TestUser"
            },
            handleSuccess = function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            handleFailure = function () {
                alert("failure");
            },
            url = 'myServer';

        Y.on('io:success', handleSuccess);
        Y.on('io:failure', handleFailure);

        Y.io(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: jsonCreateUser
        });
    });
});
```

IF that sounds any obvious to you, please explain me, really want to understand this one.

**Thanks for the help !**

Comment: Easy mistake to make, don't sweat it. You're doing good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `tap` event on `#connectBut` will bind `handleSuccess` to `io:success`.

You must move the code binding `handleSuccess` to `io:success` out of the `tap` event handler.

[Code example](http://jsfiddle.net/qezvh52h/).

Comment: That worked perfectly ! I got both the answer and an explanation that allowed me to progress ! Thanks a lot =)